# Sort emails in conversations by date of first email rather than date of most recent email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a bunch of email messages in a folder, I am working through them chronologically, and it would be useful to be able to go back an forth without any further correspondence about an email changing the sort order.

I could always simply not use conversations, but ideally I'd still like to have the messages grouped by thread, but without them getting bumped to the top if I get a reply to the thread.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried just sorting by clicking "subject" in the view mode?

[image: Outlook Bar]

That will keep all like subjects together